# How to remove index segment in my codeigniter url

Tags: codeigniter, api, rest, url, uri

I am using rest controller api by phil sturgeon this is the url
**paycent/user/index/id/1**. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

you need to set route for that.

set route in your **application/config/routes.php** file

```
$route['paycent/user/id/(:any)'] = 'paycent/user/index/id/$1';
```

Note : If **paycent** is your project name than remove it from your route. and for creating link you just need to write `<?php echo site_url('paycent/user/id/1'); ?>`. It will redirect to **index**method.

Answer (score -1):

In `application/config/config.php` :

Change

```
$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';
```

to

```
$config['index_page'] = '';
```